# Multiple classes selector

Tags: jquery, class, double, selector

I do not understand why this is not working

I have anchors with multiple classes

```
<div id="left_menu">
<ul>
    <li>
                    <h1>Nobelova</h1>
                    <a class="manned-flight active" href="#manned-flight">View</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h1>Vízia</h1>
                    <a class="frameless-parachute" href="#frameless-parachute">View</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h1>Projekt</h1>
                    <a class="english-channel" href="#english-channel">View</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h1>Lokalita</h1>
                    <a class="about" href="#about">View</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h1>Mapa</h1>
                    <a class="about" href="#about">View</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

I just need to test if some of that anchors has class "active" and no matter if there is manned-flight,parachute-flight,sky-flight class in first place. Why this code not working?

```
if($("#left_menu ul li a").hasClass('active')){
//do something
}
```

this code never get active class anchor when this "active" class is added by another piece of code

```
if($(document).scrollTop() >= section1Top && $(document).scrollTop() < section2Top){
    $('#left_menu ul li a.manned-flight').addClass('active');
```

Comment: This is all wrapped within a div / ul / li? Why not use an id instead of class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When performing a test like `.hasClass()` on a selector which returns multiple elements, it will only perform the test on the first element, so `$("#left_menu ul li a").hasClass('active')` is equivalent to `$("#left_menu ul li a").first().hasClass('active')`, so it will only ever resolve to true if the first link has the `active` class.

If all you need is to determine if one (or more) of the links has the `active` class, just check the length of the returned collection when targeting the `active` class ([working example](http://jsfiddle.net/F7u5j/2/)):

```
if($("#left_menu ul li a.active").length > 0)
{
    console.log($("#left_menu ul li a.active").length);
}
```

If you need to know the actual link that has the `active` class use `.each()` to iterate over the collection ([working example](http://jsfiddle.net/F7u5j/)):

```
$("#left_menu ul li a").each(function()
{
    if($(this).hasClass('active'))
    {
        console.log($(this).attr('href'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, your code is working but only when I manually add class "active" to html. When this "active" class is generated by mentioned piece of code than non of your examples working. Problem must be somewhere on that piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no li tag in your code.

Change to:

$("#left_menu a").hasClass('active')

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if($("#left_menu.ul.li.a").hasClass('active')){
//do something
}
```